# Can spacy recognize bigrams as a single token?

Tags: python, spacy

I am parsing the [Game of Thrones script](https://www.kaggle.com/albenft/game-of-thrones-script-all-seasons) so that I can use word2vec.  The problem is the parsing of the proper nouns. Take for example:

```
s = "The Night's Watch is a joke to you, is it? Is that what we are, Lannister? An army of jesters in black?"
```

Here is sample code:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
[token.lemma_ for token in nlp(s) if not token.is_stop]
```

This gives:

```
['Night',
 'Watch',
 'joke',
 ',',
 '?',
 ',',
 'Lannister',
 '?',
 'army',
 'jester',
 'black',
 '?']
```

I would really like Night's Watch to be recognised as a single token, e.g. Night's_Watch.

Can spacy do this?

Comment: Why the close vote?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `spacy's` `noun chunks` feature. Noun chunks are a noun plus the words describing the noun e.g. "night watch", "a joke":

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

doc = nlp("The Night's Watch is a joke to you, is it? Is that what we are, Lannister? An army of jesters in black?")
list(doc.noun_chunks)
```

Output:

```
[The Night's Watch, a joke, you, it, what, we, An army, jesters]
```

If you instead want to get all the true bigrams in a given text then you can use `nltk.util.ngrams` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use a `for` loop with `if`, `elif` and `else`:

```
lst = ['Night','Watch','joke',',','?',',','Lannister','?','army','jester','black','?']
bigrams = ['Night Watch'] # You can put as many bigrams as you like
new = []

for i,v in enumerate(lst):
    if i+1 < len(lst):
        b = f'{v} {lst[i+1]}'
        if b in bigrams:
            new.append(b)
        elif f'{lst[i-1]} {v}' in bigrams:
            pass
        else:
            new.append(v)

print(new)
```

Output:

```
['Night Watch',
 'joke',
 ',',
 '?',
 ',',
 'Lannister',
 '?',
 'army',
 'jester',
 'black',
 '?']
```

#### UPDATE: The bigrams are unknown:

```
lst = ['Night','Watch','joke',',','?',',','Lannister','?','army','jester','black','?']
new = []

for i,v in enumerate(lst):
    if i+1 < len(lst):
        if v.istitle() and lst[i+1].istitle():
            new.append(f'{v} {lst[i+1]}')
        elif lst[i-1].istitle() and v.istitle():
            pass
        else:
            new.append(v)

print(new)
```

Output:

```
['Night Watch',
 'joke',
 ',',
 '?',
 ',',
 'Lannister',
 '?',
 'army',
 'jester',
 'black',
 '?']
```

Comment: Thank you but I was looking for something else.  There are lots of bigrams like that and I was hoping spacy could automatically detect them (maybe using NER)?

Comment: @fomin I don't know `spacy` that well, but I updated my answer to serve the same purpose.

Comment: Thanks but this requires you to know the bigrams in advance. That's not what I am looking for,

Comment: @fomin Is there a rule as to what counts as a bigram?

Comment: Spacy has something called NER which I think attempts to work that out for single words.

Comment: @fomin Updated.